# 2017 the year of “sexual misconduct”

Tags: meaning, american-english, connotation, phrase-origin

Since October 2017 when the movie producer, [Harvey Weinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Weinstein_sexual_abuse_allegations), was accused of multiple acts of rape and sexual violence in the US and in the UK, the term “sexual misconduct” has been constantly in the news.  At the last count, the number of women who have spoken up, and denounced Weinstein has risen to 82.

During this time, several legal terms assigned to *sexual* have been used by journalists, whose meanings seem to overlap; sexual abuse, sexual assault, sexual harassment and sexual misconduct.

According to Wikipedia, ***sexual misconduct*** comprises all of the above, and it is defined as *[any conduct of a sexual nature that is without consent, or has the effect of threatening or intimidating the person against whom such conduct is directed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_misconduct)*. Wikipedia does not mention when this broad term was first created nor if there are any exceptions. I was wondering if the following case could be an exception.

On January 2nd, 2018, the American senator of Minnesota, Al Franken, will resign from the Senate due to accusations of sexual misconduct by eight women. The first of the eight accusations–and the most damning– was a [photo](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2017/11/al-franken-that-photo-and-trusting-the-women/545954/) showing the then-comedian Franken *pretending* (there was *no* actual physical contact) to grope a woman's breasts while she was sleeping. The photo was taken in 2006.

I wonder if he had drawn a moustache on her face, or duct-taped her and a man to their seats, would the term *sexual misconduct* still have been used? I have a feeling it would have. Although I would classify these pranks as being childish; disrespectful and potentially humiliating for the victims involved, somehow the term “misconduct” seems to be used ubiquitously and has recently earned darker and more sinister overtones.

For elucidation I searched on Etymonline, while the entry for **[misconduct](https://www.etymonline.com/word/misconduct)** is brief and to the point, the dictionary completely fails to mention its related expression, *sexual misconduct*

> 1710, "bad management, neglect;" see mis-  + conduct (n.). Meaning "wrong conduct" is attested from 1729.

- What is the current meaning and history of the term *sexual misconduct*?
  Is its meaning changing in light of recent events?
- Did this phrase originate in the UK or in the US?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - it is not clear what answer you may expect for the difference between “sexual misconduct, misconduct and violation” apart from their literal  difference.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Do you suppose it's a convenient (and printable) euphemism for the technically-accurate or slang terms for the actual behavior? I would agree that the phrase has been around for a century or more, but might suggest that it may have been specially purposed in more recent decades. Without the benefit of the slightest research, I'd suggest one might look at the language with which the press described the Profumo scandal in Britain in the 1960s, or the behavior of accused Catholic priests in the US and elsewhere since the 1990s.

Comment: I have to downvote this question for lack of clarity and, in my opinion, at least the appearance of making some kind of charged statement about the subject matter.  You may not actually be making any kind of deliberate statement, but the way you've written extensively about the details of the accusations and events will attract attention to those details, rather than the question.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that discussion (in fact I'm glad it's happened), but it's a thing for reddit, not stackexchange.

Comment: It's called context and research.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I would respond that there is a lot in your request that is immaterial to the question.  For instance, noting the year the photo of Franken was taken.  As a reader, I feel overwhelmed by what you are calling "context and research" and actually find it somewhat difficult to see what you are actually asking.  You haven't even indicated the nature of your question in the title, choosing instead to talk about the nature of the past year.

Comment: In fact, if I were to take the actual question, "What is the history of the term sexual misconduct? Did it originate in the UK or in the US?", I would have a hard time seeing where any of your research or context actually relates to it.  The vast majority of your exposition speaks about current events and your personal impression of the term, but there is no indication that you've actually looked for historical occurrences yourself, which is supposedly the meat of your question.  This feels more like you are questioning the use of the label than you are asking for its history.

Comment: Unrelated to the issues I've raised, I'd also like to say that it is probably unrealistic to expect a reference entry on "misconduct" to necessarily consider "sexual misconduct" a related term, at least etymologically.  There are so many potential types of misconduct that I think the see-also list would become unwieldy.  That would be akin to expecting "repair" to include "see also: computer repair".  In both cases, the word would be more of a category including the extended terms.  I don't mean to be semantically picky here, mind you--rather, I'm trying to help you better execute your search.

Comment: @ab2 I have done my best, but I lack the literary prowess and clarity of thought to express my question properly. I suspect the question is too "sensitive" a subject, and users are wont to dirtying their hands. It's a pity because, tell the truth, I really like my question. If you have any suggestions, I'm all ears. P.S I will not delete references to Al Franken because it was his unique case (in as much he did not sexually harass the women, in the traditional sense of the misdemeanor, or physically forced his manhood onto them)  that gave me the impetus to post my question in the first place.

Comment: I think you might concentrate on the usage of the term sexual misconduct, and use recent fact just as a background without specific references. “Sexual misconduct” has been used for more than a century and its meaning is most likely  different from what  it used to be a century ago. Recent facts may have added a stronger connotation to its usage.

Comment: There are a lot of definitions available about sexual misconduct and most of them are from university papers  or legal documents, apparently mainly from American sources. The term, as you pointed out, is a broad definition that includes different offensive behaviors related to sex which are often categorized as sex  crimes. https://www.google.it/search?q=sesual+misconduct&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=vni&ei=HZVHWsTyJYP_UpyjpYAJ&start=0&sa=N&biw=768&bih=1004&dpr=2

Comment: As noted in this article: “* In the world of Hollywood, meanwhile, Matt Damon took a beating on social media last week for trying to place misbehavior on a “spectrum” of gravity. “There’s a difference between, you know, patting someone on the butt and rape or child molestation, right?” he said to ABC’s Peter Travers. “Both of those behaviors need to be confronted and eradicated without question, but they shouldn’t be conflated, right?” Actress Alyssa Milano and others quickly pushed back with a frustrated tweet that **all forms of sexual misconduct “hurt***.”   ./.

Comment: “*Part of the challenge in getting a handle on these scandals **is that a cultural shift has occurred.***” https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2017/12/what-does-sexual-misconduct-actually-mean/548807/

Comment: @user159691 too scared to post an answer? :) Sexual misconduct is in the title, and the in the second and last paragraph. What do I do? Strip everything else out? The specific reference is what spurred me to ask in the first place. ahh...what the heck.

Comment: I am not scared, I am just trying to help. The subject  is interesting and has linguistic implications, but it is also a very sensitive issue as you well know. It is closely  related to the evolution of relationship between genders in  the last, say, one hundred   years. I still have to ascertain what sexual misconduct meant in the first decades of the 20th century. I suspect it just referred to the personal conduct of the offender, with little or no importance of the consequences for the offended person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer may be downvoted for being overly speculative, but I will try to back it up with sources when possible.

It seems to me that **sexual misconduct** in its modern use is a term deliberately adopted by the legal and media communities because of its broad scope, which can encompass non-criminal but potentially "civil" legal acts such as adultery, which can be a legal factor in divorce proceedings, extending all the way to criminal violations as heinous as *rape*.

The earliest print use I found in newspaper archives was in *The London Times*, in a discussion on divorce and the various forms of *misconduct* that could be considered in a divorce proceeding.  The article takes a very religious, conservative perspective, and describes **sexual misconduct** as part of this list of civil "misconducts."

This passage is not easy to follow; it essentially discusses case law regarding whether adultery can be considered under divorce proceedings as a form of misconduct if the partner also committed adultery afterward, and discusses factors of neglect, cohabitation, abuse, and rape, in a lengthy legalese piece.

> I think that the reason why, in former times at any rate, the character of some kinds of **sexual misconduct** on the part of the respondent would have been held to justify the exercise of discretion, and the allowance of a divorce, in favour of a guilty petitioner, was that it rendered the assumption of cohabitation, which the law regarded as the necessary consequence of refusal of a degree, impossible.

- [**1897** - *The Times* (London, England) 9 April 4/3](https://www.newspapers.com/image/32648601/?terms=%22sexual%2Bmisconduct%22)

The article uses the word "misconduct" 19 times and "sexual misconduct" twice, in both cases referring to adultery, and in all cases referring to civil law, though criminal acts are discussed.

---

### This brings me to my main point...

...which is that **sexual misconduct** is both **broad** and **euphemistic**.

I call it "broad" because "sexual misconduct" can include anything from adultery to unwanted requests for dates from a boss to violent rape.  All of these are aspects of a larger social problem that the public and media are beginning to focus on seriously.

Consider the comedian Louis C.K. who has been accused of exposing himself to women, or Minnesota Sen. Al Franken who has been accused of groping and unwanted kissing.  Now consider Roy Moore who has been accused of making sexual advances with underage girls.  Now consider Harvey Weinstein whose alleged offenses have reached the level of rape.  Even U.S. President Donald Trump has a legal history of [allegedly raping his own wife](http://gawker.com/the-time-donald-trumps-ex-wife-accused-him-of-brutally-1721129617), but this is usually wrapped into that broad umbrella "sexual misconduct," alongside his other alleged offenses that also include unwanted kissing, groping and sexual advances.

Now, the media is trying to cover a social movement that encompasses accusations that span across this spectrum of offenses and civil misbehaviors.  To describe the social movement that is arising around the accusations in a broad way, the term **sexual misconduct** serves well, in that it does not imply a criminal act as **violation** might, but it also does not have the potential for being misleadingly benign, like **sexual harassment** might.

I also call it **euphemistic** because "sexual misconduct" is often used in circumstances where the speaker or writer is uncomfortable making a more specific, more shocking and potentially defamatory statement about a person's actions.  For instance, while there is substantial evidence that Harvey Weinstein and Donald Trump have committed **rape**, saying so is risky for journalists, legal experts, analysts, and anyone else in a position of authority because the accusation is perceived as one of the most heinous in all of society.

Hence, while many of the perpetrators in the news today could be said to have committed sexual assault or rape, "a discussion on sexual misconduct" could mean discussing systemic rape culture or it could mean talking about appropriate behavior in the workplace. It's a catch-all that's useful for discussion in the context of a social movement where there is a broad range of "misconduct."